# Confluent JDBC Source Connect gives NullPointerException in transform

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

This is really weird. 
In my DB, when I execute this SQL:

`select count(*) from mySchema.myTable where some_col = '2'`

the result is: 26000000

When the QUERY in connector config is set to this and I run the connector:

```
QUERY="select * from mySchema.myTable where some_col = '2' order by primary_key, sec_key limit 26000000"
```

the connector works with NO PROBLEM and I am able to consume all the messages.

However, when the QUERY in connector config is set to this and I run the connector:

```
QUERY="select * from mySchema.myTable where some_col = '2' order by primary_key, sec_key"
```

the connector gives me this exception:

```
[2019-12-23 22:51:16,671] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=HIVE_JDBC_BATCH_SOURCE-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:177)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
                at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
                at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
                at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:50)
                at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:293)
                at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:229)
                at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
                at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey.applyWithSchema(ValueToKey.java:85)
                at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey.apply(ValueToKey.java:65)
                at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.lambda$apply$0(TransformationChain.java:50)
                at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
                at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
                ... 11 more
```

Here are the configs:

[2019-12-23 22:51:00,681] INFO ConnectorConfig values:

```
    config.action.reload = restart
    connector.class = io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
    errors.log.enable = false
    errors.log.include.messages = false
    errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
    errors.retry.timeout = 0
    errors.tolerance = none
    header.converter = null
    key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
    name = HIVE_JDBC_BATCH_SOURCE
    tasks.max = 8
    transforms = [createKey, extractString]
    value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
```

[2019-12-23 22:51:00,681] INFO EnrichedConnectorConfig values:

```
    config.action.reload = restart
    connector.class = io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
    errors.log.enable = false
    errors.log.include.messages = false
    errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
    errors.retry.timeout = 0
    errors.tolerance = none
    header.converter = null
    key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
    name = HIVE_JDBC_BATCH_SOURCE
    tasks.max = 8
    transforms = [createKey, extractString]
    transforms.createKey.fields = [mySchema.primary_key]
    transforms.createKey.type = class org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
    transforms.extractString.field = mySchema.primary_key
    transforms.extractString.type = class org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
    value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
```

[2019-12-23 22:51:00,686] INFO StringConverterConfig values:

```
    converter.encoding = UTF8
    converter.type = key
```

[2019-12-23 22:51:00,686] INFO JsonConverterConfig values:

```
    converter.type = value
    schemas.cache.size = 1000
    schemas.enable = false
```

[2019-12-23 22:51:00,701] INFO ProducerConfig values:

```
    acks = all
    batch.size = 100000
    bootstrap.servers = xxx
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 2147483647
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
    linger.ms = 10
    max.block.ms = 9223372036854775807
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 1
    max.request.size = 10485760
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 310000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
```

[2019-12-23 22:51:00,810] INFO JdbcSourceTaskConfig values:

```
    batch.max.rows = 100
    catalog.pattern = null
    connection.attempts = 5
    connection.backoff.ms = 60000
    connection.password = null
    connection.url = xxx
    connection.user = null
    db.timezone = UTC
    dialect.name = 
    incrementing.column.name = 
    mode = bulk
    numeric.mapping = null
    numeric.precision.mapping = false
    poll.interval.ms = 86400000
    query = select * from mySchema.myTable where some_col = '2' order by primary_key, sec_key
    quote.sql.identifiers = ALWAYS
    schema.pattern = mySchema
    table.blacklist = []
    table.poll.interval.ms = 60000
    table.types = [TABLE]
    table.whitelist = []
    tables = []
    timestamp.column.name = []
    timestamp.delay.interval.ms = 0
    topic.prefix = my_topic
    validate.non.null = false
```

Sample data from DB-table:

primary_key 2C58131FF9680D5632CB1FDC27675490

sec_key 3EE

year_cd 1

year_month 201911

content_txt 2016-10-072016-10-12MEMOREX1234500172409430291.52

Sample message produced by the Connector:

{"mySchema.primary_key": "2C58131FF9680D5632CB1FDC27675490", "mySchema.sec_key": "3EE", "mySchema.year_cd": "1", "mySchema.year_month": "201911", "mySchema.content_txt": "2016-10-072016-10-12MEMOREX1234500172409430291.52"}

Comment: The query isn't the issue. It's the transform, if you look at the stacktrace. Do your record values actually have dots in them? Can you show example records without the transform?

Comment: I doubt it..although, I will post a sample record (without transform) when I get a chance. There is no error with the 'LIMIT clause' and I get the error when I remove the 'LIMIT clause'

Comment: I don't think you should be using a LIMIT. AFAIK, batch.max.rows takes care of that

Comment: I understand....but the Connector fails without the LIMIT-clause !!

Comment: I don’t think limit could have any impact...Try to debug...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the bug (IMO, bug in JDBC SourceConnector)

Sample message produced by the Connector when the query has a 'LIMIT clause':

{"mySchema.primary_key": "2C58131FF9680D5632CB1FDC27675490", "mySchema.sec_key": "3EE", "mySchema.year_cd": "1", "mySchema.year_month": "201911", "mySchema.content_txt": "2016-10-072016-10-12MEMOREX1234500172409430291.52"}

Sample message produced by the Connector when the query has no 'LIMIT clause':

{"primary_key": "2C58131FF9680D5632CB1FDC27675490", "sec_key": "3EE", "year_cd": "1", "year_month": "201911", "content_txt": "2016-10-072016-10-12MEMOREX1234500172409430291.52"}

when the setting was like this: 
transforms.extractString.field=mySchema.primary_key
the connector would raise a NullPointerException, so I changed the setting to:
transforms.extractString.field=primary_key
and it works like a charm.